# Node.js: realtime conversion from jpeg images to video file

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, socket.io, jpeg

I'm using node.js and through the socket.io library I receive chunks of data that are actually jpeg images. These images are frames of a realtime video captured from a remote webcam. I'm forced to stream the video as jpeg frames. I'm looking for a way to convert on the fly these jpeg images in a video file (mpeg 4 or mjpeg file). Does node have a library that can do this? I already took a look at the [Node-fluent-FFMPEG](https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg) library but the only examples given were about conversions of jpeg files to a video and not a conversion on the fly from a stream of jpeg images. Or alternatively, does ffmpeg for windows support a stream of jpeg images as input?

Comment: I don't really have the answer for you, but I suspect you'll have to buffer the images and encode them in chunks - most encoding algorithms require many frames in sequence to get even basic compression going.

I don't really know your use case so maybe compression doesn't matter. Maybe webRTC is an option for you?

Comment: Does it have to be a video, couldn't you draw the jpeg frames on a canvas, for example ?

Comment: Hi
Any working solution?

Answer (score 2):

FFMPEG supports streams as inputs, as stated in the [docs](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#specifying-inputs).

> You can add any number of inputs to an Ffmpeg command. An input can
>   be [...] a readable stream

So for instance it supports using

```
ffmpeg().input(fs.createReadStream('/path/to/input3.avi'));
```

which creates a [Readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable_1) from the file at `'/path/to/input3.avi'`.

I don't know anything about FFMPEG, but you may pull your messages coming from socket.io (messages [may be a Buffer](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#emit(name:string[,-%E2%80%A6]):socket) already) and wrap it with your own implementation of [Readable stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable_1).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at [videofy](https://github.com/zjhiphop/videofy/blob/master/index.js)

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var escape = require("shell-escape");
var debug = require("debug")("videofy");
var mkdirp = require("mkdirp");
var uid = require("uid2");

/*
 *  Expose videofy
 */

module.exports = videofy;

/**
 * Convert `input` file to `output` video with the given `opts`:
 *
 *  - `rate` frame rate [10]
 *  - `encoders` the video codec format, default is libx264
 *
 * @param {String} input
 * @param {String} output
 * @return
 * @api public
 */
function videofy(input, output, opts, fn) {
    if (!input) throw new Error('input filename required');
    if (!output) throw new Error('output filename required');

    var FORMAT = '-%05d';

    // options
    if ('function' == typeof opts) {
        fn = opts;
        opts = {};
    } else {
        opts = opts || {};
    }

    opts.rate = opts.rate || 10;
    opts.codec = opts.codec || 'libx264';

    // tmpfile(s)
    var id = uid(10);
    var dir = 'tmp/' + id;
    var tmp = dir + '/tmp' + FORMAT + '.jpg';


    function gc(err) {
        debug('remove %s', dir);
        exec('rm -fr ' + dir);
        fn(err);
    }

    debug('mkdirp -p %s', dir);

    mkdirp(dir, function(error) {
        if (error) return fn(error);

        // convert gif to tmp jpg
        var cmd = ['convert', input, tmp];
        cmd = escape(cmd);

        debug('exec %s', cmd);
        // covert jpg collection to video
        exec(cmd, function(err) {

            if (err) return gc(err);

            var cmd = ['ffmpeg'];

            cmd.push('-f', 'image2');
            cmd.push('-r', String(opts.rate));
            cmd.push('-i', tmp);
            cmd.push('-c:v', String(opts.codec));
            cmd.push(output);

            cmd = escape(cmd);

            debug("exec %s", cmd);

            exec(cmd, gc);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `require("child_process")` you can use ffmpeg, or there are probably npm modules to help with this.  ffmpeg will allow you to first take a list of jpegs and convert that to a video, second you can add a list (or just one) jpegs to the beginning or end of videos.